# Why won't my rows get deleted in Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to do some data transformations on a dataset in Data Factory. I wanted to delete a set of rows based on certain conditions. This is the data flow so far:

[image]

So in AlterRow1 I deleted the rows I wanted, and this is the result when I click on data preview:

[image]

As you can see, 6 rows get deleted, exactly what I wanted. However, in sink1 this is the data preview I'm getting:

[image]

The rows I wanted to delete are back and won't get deleted when I run this pipeline. I'll add that the source is an excel file from the blob storage and sink is a csv file in my blob storage.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
There are no settings in the sink to allow deletion.
[image]

Comment: Have you allowed delete operation in the sink settings?

Comment: @ray hey, there are no such settings in the sink as can be seen in my edit.

Comment: sorry for the mistake. I mixed up your csv sink settings with the SQL sink one.

Comment: Alter Row only works with database sinks, not CSV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you seem to be able to get the preview, **Alter row transformation** can result in a row (or rows) being inserted, updated, deleted, or upserted (DDL & DML actions) against your database only.

See, [Alter row transformation in mapping data flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-alter-row)

I did try to repro your exact scenario and I do see the same behavior. I can see in **AlterRow transformation's** Data review the rows marked `X` to be deleted. But the sink preview doesn't show them and all the rows from source are seen.

I could not find any particular details as to this behavior, you can reach out [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/new) and [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/1219ec2d-6c26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c) for official response.

Comment: Data preview does not take any actions on the data against your data store target. Instead, all rows will be shown (within the sampling range) with a row indicator of update, upsert, insert, or delete. To actually perform CRUD operations, you need to execute the data flow from a pipeline. Also, in this example, the user has a CSV sink. Alter Row only works with database sinks.